# Convert strings to values of my type fail

Tags: haskell

I defined a typeclass Vector as

```
data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Show, Read)
```

But when I convert from strings using code

```
read "Vector 1 2 3" :: Vector
```

It does not work. Can anyone help. Thanks!

Comment: Try `read "Vector 1 2 3" :: Vector Int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vector` is not a type, but a type constructor. `Vector Int`, `Vector Double`, `Vector (Vector String)` are types. Use

```
read "Vector 1 2 3" :: Vector <<some type here>>
```